# React and Meteor Subscription

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I am not sure if this is a limitation to React and Meteors connection as documentation suggests that it should be possible without the extra parameter.

When I call a meteor subscription in react if I do not explicitly state the parameter in the query it returns any data, ignoring the specified data in the publish function.

```
Meteor.publish("supplier", function() {
    if(this.userId) {

       var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId, { fields : { active : 1 }});
       if(user.active != this.userId || user.active != undefined){

         // This only returns 1 singular supplier - is correct
         var supplier = Supplier.find({ _id : user.active, users : this.userId });
         return supplier;

       } else {
         return this.ready();
       }
    } else {
      return this.ready();
    }
});
```

Now I call the subscription in react as so

```
getMeteorData: function () {

   var data = {}

   handle = Meteor.subscribe("supplier");

    if(handle.ready()) {
      data.supplier = Supplier.findOne(); // Returns Wrong supplier
      //data.supplier = Supplier.findOne({_id: session.get("active")}) // Returns correct supplier
      data.supplierReady = true
    }

    return data;

  },
```

This returns the first supplier in the collection not the one logged in the publish function on the server! However if I explicably pass  `{ _id : user.active}` it works!

Now it was my understanding that by doing the logic on the server within the `publish` function that I could simply use `Supplier.findOne()` but this is not the case and I don't understand why. Is this a limitation on React/Meteor or am I implementing this wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a React-specific issue, it's a result of the way `findOne` works. If you have one or more documents in your client side `Supplier` collection, `Supplier.findOne()` will just grab the first record available without reference to the document(s) you just fetched from your subscription.

This means either (a) you have more than one supplier available on the client side due to other preexisting subscriptions, or (b) you are returning more than one supplier from the `handle` subscription.

Check the state of the client side collection prior to the `handle` subscription. If there's 1 or more docs and that is the intended state of your application, then modify the client side findOne to add `{_id: user.active}` as you have before.

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Thanks for the informative answer. I understand the principal now and the issue is that multiple subscriptions of the supplier collection must exist(as you can switch between supplier). I am interested if you could elaborate or explain what you mean by `Check the state of the client side collection`. You mean just a count or query to check the client collection?

Comment: Yes, I meant you could take a look at the client collection just before the subscription is run. You could console.log a find().fetch() or a find().count() for a quick look, or you could use one of the tools that are available to inspect the collections more carefully. The one I really like and use is https://github.com/bakery/meteor-devtools - some people like to use Mongol. They just make it a bit easier as you don't have to enter commands in your code or the console.

Comment: Nice recommendation about the dev tools. Thanks!